# Can't install 14.04 alongside Windows 10 (boot device not recognizable)

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot

I already have Windows 10 Enterprise, and I'm trying to get Ubuntu 14.04 to dual boot, but the bootable device keeps saying:

```
missing operation/operating system
```

and kicks me back to my BIOS. I have Fast Boot and Secure Boot disabled, but it still doesn't seem to be able to be to installed.

Specs:

- mobo: Asus z97-a,
- CPU: Core i7-4790k
- GPU: Nvidia MSI GTX 970
- RAM: HyperX 16G DDR3
- SSD: Samsung EVO 500GB

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a Live boot USB or CD. Live Boot your computer.
Instead of Installing Ubuntu, Select Try Ubuntu.
When Ubuntu OS boots up and ready for use.
Go Terminal, Type the following commands.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

Once installation is finished.
Type `boot-repair`.
You will get the window like this.

[image]

Click Recommended Repair. It will create all Boot Menu entries.
For more details,visit [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: I tried that, did not work, it created an instance of ubuntu, but when I tried to go into it, it kicked me back into boot menu again, saying there was a boot error.